# How can i make sure that the footer stays at the bottom of the page?

Tags: angular

I have a footer component which is currently being rendered at the end of another component.
How can I make sure that it stays at the bottom of the page irrespective of other components.
My other components include a header which is at the top,a side navigation which opens when a button is clicked on the toolbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try a markup like this.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
  <nav>
    HEADER
  </nav>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    page
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <h2>footer</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.header{
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-grow: 0;
  background: #039be5;
  padding: 3px 5px;
}
.content{
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 3px 5px;
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.footer{
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-grow: 0;
  background: #eee;
  padding: 3px 15px;
}
```